# How to unpack tileset or image atlas

Tags: tiles

In order to define boundary of each tile, I need to have individual image of the tile. Is there any way to extract each image of tiles from a tileset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your tiles are the same size, then you can use [TileMage Image Splitter.](http://download.cnet.com/TileMage-Image-Splitter/3000-6675_4-10589275.html)

I've used it before, and it works fine, even for 10000xN pixel tilesets.

Comment: I just googled about it. It looks really hard to uninstall it. In addition, couldn't find who published the software.

Comment: So I just opened it up and clicked About. I found his site through his contact [link](http://tilemage.50webs.com/).

Futhermore, it does have an uninstaller--I just tried it right now and it works fine. It looks just like any other uninstaller.

Comment: It seems strange. If he want to define the boundary of each tile, would all tiles be the same size?

Comment: Err, I just gave the question my answer. I don't see how software would (easily) figure out bounds to non-tiled image sets.
As far as I know, tileset tiles are usually the same size.

Comment: **usually** they do xD